# Java Serialization : Can not produce run time exception as specified in java docs 1.8

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to get some run time exception to verify java docs of `Serializable` interface. It says

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
>   is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

I have written some code here to test that but not getting any exception.

```
class A {
    private A() {
            System.out.println("private A");
        }
    public A(final int i) {
        System.out.println("public A");
    }
}

public class B extends A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2683305431271101335L;

    public B(final int i) {
        super(i);
        System.out.println("public B");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final B t = new B(10);
        try {
            final ObjectOutputStream oio = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
            oio.writeObject(t);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Am it doing it correctly?

Comment: @Kartic. If I do not call `super(i)` explicitly that will be compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializaiton will detect the abscense of accessible no-arg constructor only on reading object, change your code like this

```
    ObjectOutputStream oio = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1"));
    oio.writeObject(t);
    oio.close();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("1"));
    ois.readObject();
```

and you will see

Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: test.B; no valid constructor